# select2 not displaying properly in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

select2 works fine in Chrome, Opera and Safari but in Firefox the selected options are not displayed properly. Does anyone had this issue before and was able to solve it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/jEADR/2/)

This is how I am targeting the select element:

```
$("#e1").select2();
```

And this is the issue on Firefox:

[image]

Comment: could you add your code here for better understanding of the issue ?

Comment: What do you mean? I think I've already added the code I am using. I updated with a fiddle.

Comment: It works absolutely fine in FF and Chrome for me

Comment: works for me too in FF. ( Sorry didn't see the jsfiddle link up there )

Comment: Should be my css then. I will check.

Comment: Yep I was calling twice for the select2.css... daaah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling select2.css twice on the template. Once I removed the duplicated line for the css it worked.